# How to mention a user in MantisBT note

Tags: mantis

How can I mention MantisBT users in a comment?

I know…

- `#42` references the issue with id = 42.
- `~42` references the comment with id = 42; it also links to the issue which this comment was made on

How do I link users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't exactly a mention, but you can send a reminder to an user using the 'Send a reminder link' which is located in the view task page.

[image: MantisBT - send reminder]

Answer (score 4):

As of MantisBT 1.3.0-rc.2 and on [MantisHub](https://www.mantishub.com) user mentions are supported in much better way than using reminders.  You can @ mention any user via their username.  For example, @johnsmith.

Here are some aspects to take into consideration:

- Users are @ mentioned via username and not real name.
- Usernames can't use email address or spaces, otherwise @ mentions won't work.
- Mentions are supported when adding an issue (summary, description, steps to reproduce, and additional information) or a note.  It is not supported on updating such fields.
- Users that are mentioned get a dedicated email notifications about being mentioned.
- Users won't receive the email notification if they don't have access to the issue or note that they are mentioned from.
- Users that are mentioned won't receive future notifications about the issue, just because they were mentioned.  They are also not added to the monitor list for the issue.
- Mentions are hyperlinked to the user profile page.

You can find more information about it on the [MantisHub Blog post](https://blog.mantishub.com/2016/06/14/grab-your-teams-attention-with-mentions/).